# Web2py SQLFORM.grid Edit page

Tags: forms, web2py

I'm using SQLFORM.grid for my form.  The view is showing up fine and i can hide fields.  But when i go into the Edit page, i want to have certain fields not readable and not writeable.  I have set it to be readable=False before the SQLFORM.grid call and also in the request.args == 'edit'.  I can confirm it detects the edit page but for some reason, it doesn't run the read and write.

following is the controller:

```
def display_form():
  db.items.timeStamp.readable = False
  db.items.imageName.readable = False
  db.items.isCopied.writeable = True

  query = (db.items.numSold > 100)    

  default_sort_order = [db.items.numSold]


  if len(request.args) > 1 and ('edit' in request.args):        
      db.items.timeStamp.readable = False
      db.items.imageName.writeable = False
      form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, orderby=default_sort_order, create=False, 
        deletable=False, editable=True, maxtextlength=64, paginate=25, csv=False, 
        user_signature=False,
        links=[dict(header=T('Profit'),body=lambda row: row.profit), 
        dict(header=T('Image'), body = lambda rowB: A(IMG(_src=URL('static', "images/"+ 
              rowB.imageName.replace('\\','/')), _width=50, _height=50), 
              _href=URL('static', "images/"+ rowB.imageName.replace('\\','/'))))], 
              selectable=get_chosenItems
              )
  else:        
      form = SQLFORM.grid(query=query, orderby=default_sort_order, create=False, 
        deletable=False, editable=True, maxtextlength=64, paginate=25, csv=False, 
        user_signature=False,
        links=[dict(header=T('Profit'),body=lambda row: row.profit), 
        dict(header=T('Image'), body = lambda rowB: A(IMG(_src=URL('static', "images/"+ 
              rowB.imageName.replace('\\','/')), _width=50, _height=50), 
              _href=URL('static', "images/"+ rowB.imageName.replace('\\','/'))))], 
              selectable=get_chosenItems
                            )

return dict(form=form)
```

I can tell that when on the edit page, it would go in the if statement, however, it totally ignores the readables i set there.

Should i be calling the form once again within the edit page?
I feel that it's redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent fields from being included on edit forms, set both the `readable` and `writable` attributes to `False`. If you set `writable` to `False` but leave `readable` as `True`, then you'll see a read-only value for the field on the form.

Comment: I made writeable and readable = False on certain fields and placed them after the if statement. It still doesn't work: if len(request.args) > 1 and ('edit' in request.args):        
        db.items.timeStamp.readable = False
        db.items.timeStamp.writeable = False
        db.items.imageName.readable = False
        db.items.imageName.writeable = False

Comment: OH MY #*$*#!!!!  The answer is i use "writeable" as my spelling and not "writable"!! I don't understand why an error doesn't get thrown when i have been mispelling it this whole time.  Thanks a lot for your answer once again, Anthony!

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the spelling error. I think both are acceptable spellings in English, but web2py chose "writable". No exception is raised because in Python, you can add arbitrary attributes to an object (unless specifically prohibited). Perhaps we should raise an exception in the specific case of "writeable" since it's a common error.